# Does it matter what's the base OS is when packing a docker image?

Tags: docker

I read some online post. A docker image is everything from Host OS up.

Then if I pack a docker image based on an ubuntu host OS, will it work on a boot2docker host OS??

Since boot2docker is a stripped-down version, will it be missing some libs or bins which is required by the packed image?

Answer (score 0):

The container only uses the kernel from the host, everything else must be inside the image.

It shouldn't matter from what OS the libraries inside are, you only care for the application to work as expected.